# Which sentence is correct and why?

Tags: grammar, present-perfect, past-perfect

Which is the correct sentence below?

- *You never asked how I have been.*
- *You never asked how I had been.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where should we use 'has/have been' and 'had been'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44106/where-should-we-use-has-have-been-and-had-been)

Comment: Thanks John and why are you Asking that here, rather than somewhere like English Language Users?

Answer (score -1):

*You never asked how I have been* is incorrect as the time reference in *never asked* is the past, and *I have been* refers to the present. It can however be rewritten into *You never asked how I was* (meaning: *You never asked 'How are you?'.*)

*You never asked how I had been* is correct (meaning: *You never asked 'How have you been?'.*)

Comment: Oh. What I mean is the second of the two original sentences is correct. The first one would be - if corrected as shown. But OK, I probably should add an explanation...

Comment: OK, but what about this one: "You have never asked how I have been". Is it correct?

Comment: @JohnDee I guess so. However, my non-native speaker's intuition tells me more natural would be "You never ask how I am".